# Openstack- setting up bridge

Tags: networking, bridge, openstack

I have installed openstack pike- all in one node set up (not using devstack).

My host: Single NIC, ubuntu server 16.04. I added a bridge network using brctl command- br0

Ip range of host 134.x.x.x. Static ip of bridge 10.0.0.11 with gateway 10.0.0.1

In the linuxbridge-agent file in neutron, I gave br0 as my provider interface. Openstack is working fine, am able to launch instance with floating ip-range 10.0.0.101-10.0.0.250 with gateway 10.0.0.1.

Instance is up and running, but am unable to ping from host to instance. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour, you can not ping from host to private IP instance.

If you want to ping from the host you have two options:

- assign a floating ip to the vm
- from the host, ping through the network namespace of the instance, something like: 
  `# ip netns exec qrouter-... ping ...`